# Is there an alternative expression for 'opening band' or 'opening act'?

Tags: expressions, slang, synonyms

The question says it all.

Together with a colleague we were looking for this. We both had the feeling that there's another way to say it.

Comment: There might be, but `opening act` is universally understood. So another way to say it might not be clear to all.

Comment: The late-nineteenth-century theatre had "curtain raisers", but I don't think that would do here.

Comment: I am voting to close because this question does not seem constructive. It's just soliciting a list of opinions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Support act" is also used a lot.

Comment: My dictionary says "supporting act". Probably a synonym.

Answer (score 5):

"Warm up" act?  I associate that more with comedians though rather than bands.

eta:  Of course, support act as tinyd says.

Comment: It works for both. Anyway, occasionally bands use comedians for this purpose. Plus there are musical comedy acts...

Comment: [Warm-up band](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22warm-up+band%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22warm-up+band%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3z5ET_HqNMap8QOks_m2Aw&ved=0CB4QpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1950%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2030&tbm=bks&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=a5a7d9d73a2581d9&biw=1359&bih=885) is common enough even in writing. *Warm-up* is applicable to an opening act in *any* type of performance.

Answer (score 2):

We've used the slight variation openers.   The band we're seeing tonight has three openers.   You could also just use with or featuring if you're need this info for promotional materials or tickets.